# Can we have stratified L?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Can one build a hierarchy of stratified constructible stages? That is a hierarchy that is built in a manner similar to Godel's [constructible universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe) L, but with additionally requiring that the defining formulas must be also [stratified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratification_(mathematics)#In_set_theory)!

> If that can be built, then my main question is whats the stance of choice in that hierarchy, would choice be satisfied internally in every limit stage of that hierarchy? Can choice fail?

Comment: The second condition is confusing. Since $\omega$ is bound to be in any reasonable transfinite stage of the constructible hierarchy, if $L_\alpha$ knows that every two sets are equinumerous, then it knows that all sets are countable, and therefore it knows that the axiom of choice holds.

Comment: yea that's right. there is no need for that condition really. I'll correct that. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a good question to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Glad to see someone taking an interest in this stuff!
All but one of the Goedel operations are stratified, and the one that isn't is the existence of $\in$ "locally."  Replace this operation by one that gives you the local version of $\in$ composed with singleton, so that you get
$A \cap \{\langle \{x\},y \rangle: x \in y \in B\}$.  You can then prove an exact analogue of the original result that anything closed under the rudimentary functions and power set is a model of $\Delta_0$ separation - for the stratified operations.  Any set closed under the stratrud functions and power set is a model of stratified $\Delta_0$ separation.  This actually gives a finite axiomatisation of NF.  Naturally one wonders about what happens if one tries to construct an analogue of $L$ in the fashion and the (annoying) answer is that what one gets depends very sensitively on how often one "sweeps up."  The more often you sweep up the more of $L$ you get.  I have some quite extensive notes on this, but they are from about 10 years ago and i would need to do some archaeology.  I will if pressed.

Comment: Why AC fails? How far is your stratified constructibility from Noah's presentation in his answer?

Comment: Sorry - a typo:A∩{<{x},y>:x,y∈B}.  should be A∩{<{x},y>:x \in y; x x, ∈B}.  Sorry.

Comment: along the same lines, Jech's G3 would be: $G_3(X,Y)= [P_1(X) \times Y] \cap [\subseteq]$.

Comment: Don't welcome him to MO. He has more than a handful of these accounts lying around.

Answer (score 5):

*My original answer was quite wrong. The present answer is intended to highlight the issue I got tripped up on.*

For any set $\Phi$ of formulas we can consider the "iterated $\Phi$ comprehension" analogue of $L$, which I'll call "${}^\Phi L$," defined in the obvious way: ${}^\Phi L_0=\emptyset$ and we take unions at limit levels, and ${}^\Phi L_{\alpha+1}$ is the set of all subsets of ${}^\Phi L_\alpha$ definable using formulas from $\Phi$ (with parameters from ${}^\Phi L_\alpha$ allowed).

While we do have ${}^\Phi L=L$ whenever $\Phi$ is strong enough to define the [Godel operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_operation#:%7E:text=In%20mathematical%20set%20theory%2C%20a,the%20constructible%20sets%20from%20ordinals.), the set $\mathsf{strat}$ of stratified formulas is not such a $\Phi$, the culprit operation being $\mathfrak{F}_2$. So the following remains open (contra the previous version of this answer):

> Is ${}^\mathsf{strat}L=L$?

[Forster has introduced](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Etf/strZF.pdf) his own "stratified analogue" $Sr$ of $L$ *(although on a couple occasions Forster uses "$S$" instead)*. However, his construction is via a modification of the usual list of Godel functions, so I *also* don't see the answer to the following question:

> Is ${}^\mathsf{strat}L=Sr$?

Certainly ${}^\mathsf{strat}L$ lies between $Sr$ and $L$, but that's not very interesting.  I suspect that in fact we do have ${}^\mathsf{strat}L=Sr$, but at the moment I don't see the proof. Note that Forster shows $Sr\not\models\mathsf{AC}$, so this would answer the OP's question.

Comment: I came to know that AC actually fails in stratified L. This is something I've just knew last night. The reason is because the formula used in choice in usual L is non-stratified. Anyhow.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar I believe that is incorrect. Just because the obvious formula defining something is non-stratified doesn't mean it doesn't get built anyways by iterating stratified comprehension. Unless I'm missing something fairly simple, as I say in my answer "stratified $L$" is in fact just usual $L$ and so in particular satisfies choice.

Comment: As I said I myself didn't know of that, I came to know about it after I actually posted my question. It was affirmed to me that AC fails in stratified L, also I came to know that a lot of work had been done in this area, I'm not aware of the details really.

Comment: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~tf/strZF.pdf

Comment: In your remarks you said stratification is rich enough to define Godel's operations, but G3 operation is not stratified.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Each of the original list appears to be stratified, though. Just because the obvious definition of Jech's G3 isn't stratified, doesn't mean that we don't still get it. Note that the structure Forster defines as 'stratified L' isn't built in terms of iterated definability of any kind but rather closure under a particular set of functions, so - although I could be wrong - there is no obvious contradiction between his result and my answer.

Comment: No even in the original list J2 is not stratified and is not stratifiable at all. There is an operator which you can call as the membership operator, this is NOT stratifiable at all.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Whoops, quite right, I missed that. Of course that doesn't reslove the question you've posed necessarily, since per my previous comment Forster's construction may not be the same as the iterated definability one, but certainly my answer is wrong; you should unaccept this answer so I can delete it.

Comment: I think it can stay as a partial answer, but with modification

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar I think you should unaccept this - the question is interesting and still open as far as I can tell, and accepting my answer may dissuade others from thinking about it.

Comment: OK, I did that!